# java: How to check StringBuilder charcters to see if it contains same characters as new string request from array?

Tags: java

I want to check if a Java `StringBuilder` object contains a character.

For example I have a list of foods in an array {apple, pear, orange, peach, cherry} and I want to add a random number of these food types to the StringBuilder.

How would I check if StringBuilder contains a character?

Answer (score 35):

The `StringBuilder` class does not have a `contains()` method, but it does have an `indexOf()` method. The `indexOf()` method returns `-1` when the substring is not found.

**Example:**

```
stringBuilder.indexOf(charactersYouWantToCheck) != -1
```

Answer (score 25):

The `StringBuilder` class does not have a `contains()` method, but `String` does. So you can use `StringBuilder` to build a string by using `toString()`. Then call `contains()` on it, to check if it contains that character or string.

**Example:**

```
stringBuilder.toString().contains(characterYouWantToCheck)
```

Comment: better use indexOf

Answer (score 4):

It is of course possible to check the string by iterating through it (e.g. use indexOf()), but I would use a Set in this particular instance to add the fruits (if it already exists it will not be added again), once you're done adding fruits convert the Set into a String, e.g.

```
Set<String> fruits = new HashSet<String>();
for (String fruit: fruitSource) {
    fruits.add(fruit);
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String fruit: fruits) {
    sb.append(fruit);
    sb.append(", ");
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: The conditional checking whether `fruits` contains `fruit` is unnecessary -- adding a fruit that is already in the set leaves the set unchanged.

Comment: This is a nice solution (making a set first :) ).

Answer (score 2):

A different option is to create a `List<String>` of all of the options, and use `Collections.shuffle` to randomly permute the list. You can then join together the first n elements.

Since both `Collections.shuffle` and joining together the first n elements takes linear time, the entire process should take linear time.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be "checking" anything to do that, you should do it so that duplicates never get added in the first place. To do that:

1. start with a `List<String>` of the options

   - copy the list
   - add a random element to the result
   - remove that element.
   - Go back to 3 until you've added as many elements as you want or there aren't anymore left

Comment: Although it doesn't matter for smaller lists, it might be worth noting that I believe this takes quadratic time (or rather, if the list has n elements and you're removing m elements, it takes O(nm) time). If you use an `ArrayList`, removing an element takes O(n) time, so removing m items takes O(nm) time. For a `LinkedList`, reaching a random element in the list takes O(n) time, so reaching m elements takes O(nm) time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] fruits = { "apple", "pear", "orange", "peach", "cherry" };

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Some fruits: apple");

        Random r = new Random();
        int N = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            String toAdd;
            do {
                toAdd = fruits[r.nextInt(fruits.length)];
            } while (sb.indexOf(toAdd) != -1);

            sb.append(", " + toAdd);
        }

        System.out.println(sb);
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
Some fruits: apple, pear, orange, peach
```

---

But I agree with Michael Borgwardt on that it's a bad thing to check using index-of over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is similar to [Marc van Kempen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383163/marc-van-kempen)'s solution but smaller.

```
Set<String> fruits = new HashSet<String>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String fruit: fruits) {
    if(fruits.add(fruit)){
        sb.append(fruit);
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strb2.indexOf(String.valueOf(strb1.charAt(i))
```

`strb2` and `strb1` are objects of `StringBuilder` class. If the letter is present, it will return its index else `-1.`

Comment: strb2.indexOf(String.valueOf(strb1.charAt(i))

Answer (score 0):

Java StringBuilder doesn't have **contains** method 
So you can check whether a string or character contains in the StringBuilder as below:

```
StingBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("apple, pear, orange, peach, cherry");
if(sb.indexOf("someFruit") == -1) {
   //you can insert
} else {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//StringBuilder object

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("One Two Three");
    
    System.out.println( contains(sb, "One") );
    System.out.println( contains(sb, "Two") );
    System.out.println( contains(sb, "Five") );
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` doesn't have a `contains()` method, but it does have the `indexOf()` method. Therefore, you can check for the index of character and if it returns `-1`, the character is not present in the `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if(sb.indexOf(CharacterYouWantToCheck) != -1){
   //sb contains character
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I iterate through the String to find a matching char in the StringBuilder using `chars().forEach()`

```
public static void findMatch(String s){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("can");
    s.chars().forEach(i -> {

        if(sb.indexOf(String.valueOf((char)i))!= -1)
            System.out.println("Found char is "+String.valueOf((char)i));
    });
```